# How can I query in Django to a table with multiple conditions?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a table with fields `channel_id`, `message_id` and `status`. Each row in this table represents a message from a channel. The status can be SENT, DELIVERED or SEEN. When a user sends a message, a row is added to this table with the status SENT. When a user reads that message, another row is added with the status SEEN. So, for one message, I have multiple rows.
I want to retrieve the rows from this table which have not the SEEN status, so I am able to know which message is not read.
Is there a way of doing that with only one query to the database?

Edit: I want to make something like a sub query. So, if I have the following data:

```
[channel_id = 1, message_id = 1, status = 'DELIVERED'],
[channel_id = 1, message_id = 1, status = 'SEEN'],
[channel_id = 1, message_id = 2, status = 'DELIVERED']
```

the query gives me only the second, because I know it is the message which has not been seen.

Comment: Table.objects.exclude(status=SEEN) or Table.objects.filter(status__in=[SENT, DELIVERED])

Answer (score 0):

The below query will give you a list of statuses added for each message. using this you can check weather message is been read or not.

```
  TableName.objects.filter(channel_id=channel_id, message_id=message_id).value_list('status', flat=True);
```